# How can I buy Scout rifle as Secondary Weapon in Counter Strike 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I am not sure but I think I saw a video in which the player had a secondary weapon other than the Pistols.
I tried to buy the weapons, but it only adds to primary weapon.
Is there any way that I can have Carbine as primary and Scout rifle in secondary together?
Thanks

Comment: Maps or mods only.

Comment: is there any way that i can pick up scout rifle from dead players and keep it as secondary weapon

Comment: No, the Scout is a primary weapon. So, only in maps/mods that allow you to carry two primary weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The only way to have several *primary* weapons is to play on some maps that give you weapons at the beginning of a round.